# Android sdk-component: add support for gnustl_static in new sdk component (application)

Tags: android, c++, sdk, native

I am creating a new SDK component (application) based on the sample device located at `/device/sample`
the idea is to port an existing application written using C++, which utilizes lots of templates, RTTI, exceptions, STL; from the documentation it is clear that if I build my application with `gnustl_static/gnustl`_shared support this will provide me with all the support I need.

Now if I am creating a NDK application, which has `Application.mk` I know adding `APP_STL := gnustl_static` in it is one way to do it.

But as the component is part of new device sdk-addon.

> Q1. I dont know how to provide Application.mk for native C++ application/component being build part of sdk-addon.
>
> Q2. As per my knowledge I only have access to Android.mk and I am looking for a way to add support for gnustl_static using only Android.mk

I have tried various combinations of following options in Android.mk without any luck

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libstdc++.a
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := gnustl_static
```

Do let me know if you have any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have decided to avoid using RTTI/exceptions and I have decided to go with stlport

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libstlport
```

I guess same should also work with gnustl.